# OTB Orfeo ToolBox - TrainImagesClassifier ERROR ITK

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, image-segmentation

When i use in QGIS 3.6 TrainImagesClassifier i obtain an error on vector file class :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

parameter io.vd is expecting a filename.

In the photo given by you, I can see a specific value for `io.vd`.

`io.vd=/path/path/train_class.gpkg|layername=train_class`

Also please include below informations:
OS Platform: Windows?
Mode of installation: OSGeo4W/build/other..
OTB version?
QGIS version: ?